# Jquery Autocomplete with custom CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

i'm working with the [default autocomplete source code](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox). Since i replaced the `jquery-ui.css` with my own css, I don't have the ability to drop down all the select box options and I don't know how to get rid of the bullets :

[image]

here is my css :

```
.ui-autocomplete {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 120px;
border-radius: 3px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #eeeeee;
}

.ui-autocomplete select {
padding: 5px 8px;
width: 120px;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
background: #eeeeee url("arrow.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.ui-autocomplete select:focus {
outline: none;

}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-corner-all:hover, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-corner-all:focus, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-corner-all:active {
background:#ff8a00!important;
color:#000;
border-radius:0;
}

 .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
background: #ff8a00;
border: none;
color:#000;
border-radius:0;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Hi--you'll probably get a quicker/better response if you can create a demonstration at jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @TonyHinkle here : http://jsfiddle.net/hichamridouane/x67pkxve/ as u can see when jquery ui is disabled my css is OK, but once you check it my css stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `.ui-menu` style

```
.ui-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
}
```

Verify the image path maybe is in other folder or just doesn't exists.

You can see a example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/x67pkxve/1/

Comment: Hello, i hope to help

First: You have the add style list-style:none in class the <ul>

Second: The element icon is one button verify this element

Comment: +1 yes sir that missing style solved the first probleme , no bullets now :) for the second problem it is not a path problem, because the whole bloc `.ui-autocomplete select {}` seems to be not interpreted (even the background is white).

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: i've included the example in the answer

Comment: @kamus your example (just like mine) works on fiddle only. i think when you enable jquery ui it just inherits some css or something...

Comment: Maybe is because you need to add a few more styles ,can you show what is your <select> showing now?

Comment: @kamus indeed i was missing some styles. also the way images are handled in the jquery-ui css file got me confused. ended up creating a custom css via http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and took what i wanted from it. thanks for your help.